# Javascript value from field shows up as [object Text] whenever added to another string

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Using jQuery 1.6.2

HTML that I'm operating on

```
<select id="langId">
    <option value="0">Argentina - Spanish</option>
    <option value="1">Brazil - Brazil English</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the string of the selected value (ie: "Brazil - Brazil English")

What I am currently using:

```
var langVal = $('#langId option[value="' + $('#langId').val() + '"]').contents();
```

This works to a point. It gives me something like `["Brazil - Brazil English"]` which I can access at `langVal[0]`

If I do `console.log(langVal[0])` then I get what I am looking for `"Brazil - Brazil English"`, but if I do something like `console.log(("The value is: " + langVal[0]));` then what I see is `The value is: [object Text]`

I have no idea what is causing this `[object Text]` to show up instead of my value. I've tried the toString() method, but it doesn't help.

The end goal is to get the text value of the selected object into a cookie. The numerical value attribute on the option elements must remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#langId option:selected").text()
```

That will get you the text of the currently selected option in your select list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$('#langId option[value="' + $('#langId').val() + '"]').contents()` you want to use `$('#langId option[value="' + $('#langId').val() + '"]').html()` or `$('#langId option[value="' + $('#langId').val() + '"]').text()`

The [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) function actually creates a new jQuery object -- not the text value you want.

Comment: Thanks John! I accepted Mark's as my answer because it was the elegant solution to the problem as a whole, but this helps me understand why my code didn't work.